# LLVM-C types equal

Tags: c, llvm

When using the [C interface to LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/dir_ba5bdc16f452288d1429bb9e178a5965.html), how do I determine whether two `LLVMTypeRef`s represent the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, if the two types were created in the same `LLVMContext` it should be the same pointer, since types are uniqued in LLVM. C API functions use `wrap` to "convert" C++ `Type` to `LLVMTypeRef`, which just uses `reinterpret_cast` on the pointer.